# forEach store output into variable and access outside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-6

I have a code passage like this:

```
tg.router._routes.forEach(function(entry){
console.log(entry._commands[0]._textPattern)
});
```

Because inside the object (entry._commands[0]._textPattern) are three items, console.log will be called three times.

How can I store "entry._commands[0]._textPattern" into a variable (could be an array) and use the variable later outside of the anonym function?

I need a different variant, because I wan't to pass the output of the forEach later all at once to a handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const something = tg.router._routes.map(entry => entry._commands[0]._textPattern);
```

Comment: as shown, this would do exactly nothing ... surely there should be a `var something =` before that code :p

Comment: true; added `const` since there's an ES6 tag :)

Comment: Someone kind would explain me what's the difference between my solution and this one? And why it pretends to be better solution than mine?

Comment: I usually prefer `map` for simple tasks like this because it is concise, more readable and doesn't require local state.